# Is $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ semisimple (as a module over itself)? (and related examples)

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Recall that an object in an abelian category is *semisimple* if it is a (finite) direct sum of simple objects. An abelian category is *semisimple* if every object is semisimple.

In studying representations of semisimple lie algebras, one often restricts to the subcategory called $\mathcal{O}_{int}$ inside the category left modules for the universal enveloping algebra, $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$.  The main theorem about $\mathcal{O}_{int}$ says it is semisimple (or, at least, that all the objects in $\mathcal{O}_{int}$ are semisimple. Perhaps one needs to check several other things to see that $\mathcal{O}_{int}$ is abelian as a subcategory).

I am new to this area and would like to motivate this restriction.

A ring $R$ is semisimple in the category of left $R$ modules iff the category of left $R$ modules is semisimple. Thus,

> Is $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ semisimple as a left $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$-module (for $\mathfrak{g}$ a semisimple Lie algebra)?

As a bonus, are there other nice examples of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$-modules that aren't semisimple?

Comment: No, $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is not a semisimple $U(\mathfrak{g})$-module. For your bonus questions, just consider Verma modules.

Comment: In categories of modules, there is no requirement that the sum be *finite*... any infinite sum of simple modules is also called semisimple.  Maybe the case is different for the nomenclature of abelian categories, or not. I just thought I'd point out it isn't quite consistent with the normal usage for modules.

Comment: @DavidHill How does one see they aren't semisimple?

Comment: A good example is to take the Verma module for sl2 with trivial head and show that the unique maximal submodule doesn't have a complement. That implies it isn't semisimple.

Comment: Just to check: Is $\mathcal{O}_{int}$ just the category of finite dimensional modules? (I can't think of any larger one which is semisimple and "natural" to define). I am mainly used to using such an $\mathcal{O}$ for the BGG category $\mathcal{O}$, with subscripts denoting various blocks (which are rarely semisimple).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think the two additional assumptions for  $\mathcal{O}_{int}$ are that the modules are integrable ($e_i$, $f_i$ act locally nilpotently) and the weights are all integral.

Comment: Hmm, so if one was to further assume that these were weight modules, this would imply that they were finite dimensional, so I assume this is not an assumption?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I looked again and it is. The reason to phrase the assumptions this way is that in the more general case when $\mathfrak{g}$ is Kac-Moody, this no longer implies finite dimension, but you can still prove all objects are semisimple.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $U(\mathfrak{g})$ were semi-simple as a $U(\mathfrak{g})$-module, then the same would be true of any quotient. However, $U(\mathfrak{g})/U(\mathfrak{g})\mathfrak{b}\cong M(0)$, where $M(0)$ is the Verma module of highest weight $0$, $\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{h}\oplus\mathfrak{n}^+$ and $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{n}^-\oplus\mathfrak{h}\oplus\mathfrak{n}^+$ is a triangular decomposition of $\mathfrak{g}$.

It is well known, and easy to check that $M(0)$ is not semi-simple. Try it for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternate, somewhat indirect approach. The [Artin-Wedderburn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Wedderburn_theorem) completely classifies semisimple rings as finite products $\prod_i M_{n_i}(D_i)$ of matrix rings over division rings. The PBW theorem implies that $U(\mathfrak{g})$ has no nontrivial zero divisors (see, for example, [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254339/why-does-the-universal-enveloping-algebra-not-have-zero-divisors)), but a semisimple ring $\prod_i M_{n_i}(D_i)$ has nontrivial zero divisors unless it's a division ring $D$.

$U(\mathfrak{g})$ is never isomorphic to a division ring unless $\mathfrak{g} = 0$; this is because it has a counit map $U(\mathfrak{g}) \to k$ to the underlying field, so can only be a division ring if this map is an isomorphism.