# Are infinite-dimensional representations of semisimple Lie algebras semisimple?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over a field of characteristic zero. It is well-known that $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple if and only if the category of finite-dimensional representations is, i.e. every finite-dimensional representation decomposes as a direct sum of simple representations. Is this true of infinite-dimensional representations as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087301/is-mathcalu-mathfrakg-semisimple-as-a-module-over-itself-and-relate) show that some Verma modules are counterexamples.

Comment: If anyone has this question in the future, here's another indirect narrative not unlike Qiaochu Yian's answer in the linked thread. It is well-known that the cohomology of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ satisfies $\dim\mathfrak{g}$-dimensional Poincaré duality. But if every $\mathfrak{g}$-module were semisimple, then every SES would split, therefore $H^0$ would be exact and have no higher derived functors. These cannot both happen unless $\dim\mathfrak{g}=0$.

Comment: This shows that $H^*(\mathfrak{g},V)$ detects infinite-dimensional non-semisimple modules, despite being on its face a finite-dimensional thing.